# Zooming in causes footer to not grow

Tags: html, css

I have a footer at the bottom of the page but when zooming in, the table in the middle of the screen grows but the footer doesn't. Is there any way, using basic HTML/CSS or any JS/CSS Framework that will allow me to continue it to grow.

```css
.footer-center-vers2 {
  position: relative;
  background: #292929;
  margin-left: 670px;
  font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,verdana;
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px;
}

.Regulations {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:1000px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="Regulations">
  <tr>
    <td class="footer-center-vers2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
      <span style="vertical-align: middle">
        <img src="small.png" border="0" alt="My Company Ltd." /><br />
        &copy; My Insurance Company Text<br />
        <br />
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

At **0%** Zoom, the table looks great but when you zoom in **>125%**, the table is no longer **100%**.  Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your table has the class `.Regulations`, for which you set a fixed width  `width:1000px;`, which interferes with the `width="100%"` you set in the `table` tag in the HTML code. Remove one of the two.